# Express custom route parameter taking values automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin-sonu:test123@cluster0.iglcf.mongodb.net/todolistDB', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const workItems = [];

const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Buy Food"
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Cook Food"
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "Eat Food"
});

let defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  Item.find(function(err, items) {
    if (items.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfull");
        }
      });
      res.render("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {
        listTitle: "Today",
        newListItems: items
      });
    }
  });

});

const listsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
});

const List = mongoose.model("List", listsSchema);

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res) {
  const customList = _.capitalize(req.params.customListName);
  console.log(customList);
  List.findOne({
    name: customList
  }, function(err, foundList) {
    if (!err) {
      if (foundList) {
        res.render("list", {
          listTitle: foundList.name,
          newListItems: foundList.items
        });
      } else {
        const list = new List({
          name: customList,
          items: defaultItems
        });

        list.save();

        res.redirect("/:" + customList);
      }
    }else{
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const newItem = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: newItem
  });

  if (listName === "Today") {
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({
      name: listName
    }, function(err, foundList) {
      foundList.items.push(item);
      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res) {
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  const listName = req.body.listName;

  if (listName === "Today") {
    Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });
  } else {
    List.findOneAndUpdate({
      name: listName
    }, {
      $pull: {
        items: {
          _id: checkedItemId
        }
      }
    }, function(err, foundItem) {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect("/" + listName);
      }
    });
  }

  res.redirect("/");
});

// app.get("/work", function(req, res) {
//   res.render("list", {
//     listTitle: "Work List",
//     newListItems: workItems
//   });
// });

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

This is my js code. Whenever I'm entering a custom address chrome gives me an error saying "page can't be loaded" and automatically takes multiple input for the the custom route parameter then it loads up with the last input.

Suppose I'm entering localhost:3000/home, the output I get for my custom parameter name is like this....

```
Home
:home
::home
:::home
::::home
:::::home
::::::home
:::::::home
::::::::home
:::::::::home
::::::::::home
:::::::::::home
::::::::::::home
:::::::::::::home
::::::::::::::home
:::::::::::::::home
::::::::::::::::home
:::::::::::::::::home
::::::::::::::::::home
:::::::::::::::::::home
:::::::::::::::::::home
Favicon.ico
:::::::::::::::::::home
Favicon.ico
Favicon.ico
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the colon here: res.redirect("/:" + customList) - ie do just res.redirect("/" + customList). You also may want to wait for the new list to be saved before actually redirecting the user in order to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. How couldn't I see something like that.

Comment: And one thing I still don't get where it's automatically taking the input Faveicon.ico from.